# Extract layers recursively (w/o knowing how many there are in a packet)

Tags: c#, pcap.net

I need to make a tool that modifies the *VLanTaggedFrame.VLanIdentifier* in a packet.
The problem is, my packets may have multiple vlan tags.

realistically it’s between 1~3 tags but I want to make a recursive procedure and not make a chain of *if* statements.

I need some way to extract every *VLanTaggedFrame* layer (into a list or array) without knowing how many there are (as long as *x.EtherType == EthernetType.VLanTaggedFrame* , but where *x* is constantly changing stack of layers).

Any idea how I can do this?

My main direction was taking the *packet.ethernet.vlantaggedframe.payload*, but it’s of *Datagram* type and there seem to be no ‘*payload*’ in *datagram* type object, so I can’t do *x = x.payload* recursively.

any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
EthernetBaseDatagram vlanParent = packet.Ethernet;
List<ILayer> vlanLayers = new List<ILayer>();
while (vlanParent.EtherType == EthernetType.VLanTaggedFrame)
{
    VLanTaggedFrameDatagram vlan = vlanParent.VLanTaggedFrame;
    vlanLayers.Add(vlan.ExtractLayer());
    vlanParent = vlan;
}
```